# Java nested if conditions or all condition in the same if

Tags: java, optimization

I have a loop iteration that contains many conditions in this form

```
if (a[k]<=x){
     if(al[k+1]==y){
         if(a[k+2]>=x){
         }
     }
}
```

Is better use Use the conditions in and in a single if in terms of performance??

```
 if ((a[k]<=x) && (al[k+1]==y) && (a[k+2]>=x)){


  }
```

Comment: Did you measure the performance? For good compiler it's trivial to optimize equally.

Comment: it doesn't matter here - go for readability

Comment: Use what you find the most readable. Performance is probably identical.

Comment: This is a nano-optimization that is unlikely to affect performance in a measurable way.  I would advise you to write the most readable code you possibly can, profile your code under realistic conditions, and only refactor when the data tells you that you should.  The JVM uses statistics to optimize at runtime; it's smarter than you are when it comes to figuring out how to run fast.

Comment: so what form according to you is more readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, aim for readability and don't prematurely optimize code.  Measure performance and if you identify this snippet of code to be a bottleneck, then start to think more seriously about the issue.

Also as stated in comments, the performance will likely be identical in this situation.  You might find different performance characteristics if you re-ordered the predicates.  Something like:

```
if(B && A && C)
```

if calculating A is inexpensive and returns false 90% of the time, and calculating B is very expensive, you could instead write:

```
if(A && B && C)
```

but again, don't shoot from the hip!  Aim first for readable code, and if your measurements identify a performance bottleneck, then consider the above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the compiler is enough "smart" to compile the two codes to the same bytecode java but, if you want my opinion, the first is better (because reading a lot of if if if is annoying).

Comment: I'm not sure for Java but, I pretty sure there is a lot of optimization of this kind. You can optimize a code before compiling it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many complex conditions in your loop like you say, consider moving them into small methods for improved readability.

```
// inside loop
if (isValid(x, y, k)) {
}

// use a less generic method name in your code
private boolean isValid(int x, int y, int k) {
    return a[k]<=x && al[k+1]==y && a[k+2]>=x;
}
```

In case you are now worried that this will cause bad performance, there is a good chance that the JVM will inline these methods.